# Are there alternative formats to RTFs or PDFs

Tags: php, drupal-6

We are using RTFs to save some data that we generate. However, our client says that this format has become old and needs a new format to use. So can anybody please suggest a new format which can be used instead of RTFs or PDFs?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Linux kernel. What kind of data are you generating?

Comment: Just ask the client what new format they would prefer. Is there some specific problem their having with RTFs or PDFs other than simply being old?

Comment: @Asaph - They dont have any problem with rtf's . Only the thing is its an old format

Comment: the English alphabet is an old format, it's a ridiculous issue to have.

Comment: @ JohnP  - We are generating some text, in tables, images, bar graphs, pie charts ...

Comment: Thank u all for the suggestions.

Comment: Depending on your client(s) ... "DOCX". For my work, "Microsoft Integration" is a big thing, so if there is a Microsoft format for it, that's probably what we're supporting ... but, more seriously, a format like Microsoft Word (say 2003 an prior) is *quite portable* these days. But please don't use it for a proper type-setting format.

Answer (score 3):

The age of a format is not really an issue unless the applications that use that format no longer support it.  For example, HTML is a fairly old format but it is still useful today.  However, there are new versions of it so if you were consuming/creating it you should be updating it to the latest version.

In your situation, the client is saying that they do not want to use RTF.  The only answer we can give you is to ask the customer for their preferences.  The RTF format will be just as usable today as it was a year ago unless the software using it changes.  Therefore, either the customer's needs have changed or their preferences have changed.  Either way, instead of guessing it would be good to know what their new requirements are.

Based upon your added specifications, you probably want to consider talking to the customer about using ODF (Open Document Format) since this can handle all of your requirements listed so far and because it is an open standard.  Here is a link to more information:

http://www.fsf.org/campaigns/opendocument/

You could also go simpler and use HTML documents.  This would allow you to ensure that there is a viewer on every machine and it would allow you to move these documents to the web easily (if that is something that might be of benefit).

Comment: @BiggsTRC - They were not suggesting any formats but they need us to suggest and implement

Comment: @malathi - I saw your comment to Tudor so I updated my answer to reflect this information.  Basically, suggest either ODF or HTML.  ODF will be a bit cleaner but HTML is more easily usable and viewable via the web.

Comment: @BiggsTRC - Thank u. I will use BIRT and ODF ..

Comment: +1 However, I would actually suggest "WORD/DOC" over ODF as Open Office, et. al, can open DOC files just fine, but Microsoft Word needs support to open an ODF file. Go figure. Also WordPad can open certain Word documents, but I'm not sure on the restrictions.

Comment: @pst - The problem with the WORD format is that it can be hard to write to.  I figured since the OP mentioned Linux (originally), PHP, and Drupal that an open source format would be best.  Good point though.

Comment: @BiggsTRC Good points. I "just use libraries" (and live in Windows) these days. It's easy to lose the coding perspectives of others.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX if it's for human eyes.  XML if it's used as input for programs.  ODF if you need a WYSWYG editor.

Comment: +1 However, I would actually suggest "WORD/DOC" over ODF as Open Office, et. al, can open DOC files just fine, but Microsoft Word needs support to open an ODF file. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try JSON, XML, HTML, excel and many, many other. What do you need the output for?

And by the way - in PDF you can really format your data however you want and need - even though this also is an old format, it is still suited for any types of read only documents

**Edit**

You should take a look at [**BIRT reporting**](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage.php) and [**BIRT output formats**](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/wiki/index.php?title=BIRT%3aOutput_Formats). It supports output as HTML, Paginated HTML, PDF, WORD, XLS, and PostScript. It also has an API so you can integrate it with your solution.

Comment: We ned to output the participant details, some text, bar graphs, pie charts , images so plz suggest me a new format that can be used.

Comment: I edited the answer to give you a possible easy and flexible solution

Comment: Thank u so much.. I will try this BIRT output format